# PHP access CodeIgniter class from file executed by CLI

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, command-line-interface

I have a `CI_Model` with a Class called `Xray`. I have a controller class called `Pages` that handles all my pages within the application. One of these pages is called `worker.php`. I execute `worker.php` using `Supervisord` by the CLI.

I want to be able to access `Xray`'s functions from `worker.php`, but not through the command line (I won't be using the command line after `worker.php` is executed).

Comment: a "normal page" means a controller class? Is Xray "Xray_model" ? Your language is a little unclear - can you explain your structure?

Comment: I clarified my intent a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code necessary to include CodeIgniter functionality in a script loaded externally:

```
ob_start();
include('/path/to/your/index.php');
ob_end_clean();

$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->load->model('xray');
```

So the problem was that there was no `CI` instance and therefore nothing would load.

Taken from [Ellislabs Forums](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/101620/#716311)

Answer (score 1):

Load Xray as either a model or library, whichever is more appropriate, and access normally

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    function worker()
    {
        $this->load->library('Xray');
        echo $this->xray->my_func();
    }

}
```

Comment: I can access the worker.php file from a browser and access anything CI related just fine, but when it's executed from CLI I get errors like `PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`. So what is different? It's like the worker.php is detached from everything else because of how it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `$this` is current `null`.

I just call the parents constructor first:

```
function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();
}
```

If you inspect `parent`, you will see `class CI_Controller` and from there the `function __contruct()` will help you to boot upp correctly.

Now your `$this` is an object and you can do

`$this->config->load()` or `$this->load->library('Xray');`